# How to have Eclipse IDE (Java) show suggestions without automatically inserting them

Tags: java, eclipse

I was using Eclipse IDE to make some classes, and I wanted to have some suggestions be shown to make easing into Java after not using for a year easier. I read Online, and I know Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Auto Assist Triggers For Java > .qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm<QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM. However, when I do this, it will automatically insert the suggestions, even if I don't want it to.

I edited all of my other settings to figure out if another setting was making this happen, but from what I tested (all of the Java > Editor section of preferences except for the Folding Section) it was the Auto Assist Activation setting. I have attached a GIF of a screen recording of what I was talking about with the suggestions automatically inserting themselves.

[image: Hopefully a GIF to show my problem (I appologize for bad quality)]

[image: Image of my Settings in Content Assist]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **preferences > *Java > Editor > Content Assist*** (which is shown in your second screenshot) you have to **enable *Disable insertion triggers except 'Enter'***. Otherwise, also <kbd>Space</kbd> will select a proposal.